# Kivy remove Popup overlay

Tags: python, kivy

I use Kivy Popup the following way:

```
<AlertPopup@Popup>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "Notice"
    background: ''
    size_hint: (None,None)
    pos_hint: {'top': 0.9, 'right': 1.0}
    overlay_color: 0, 0, 0, 0.5
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 243, 253, 18, 0.48
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos[0], self.pos[1]
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                size_hint: .15, 1.0
                text: 'X'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
            Label:
                text: 'Some message here'
```

When the popup is shown, there is an overlay, for which the `overlay_color: 0,0,0, 0.5` which I setup on purpose so I can see it.
What I want, is for it to be removed, because when popup is shown I can't click on the rest of the application.

I'm using Python 3.9 and Kivy 2.1.0

[image]

I want to be able to click the area that surround the Popup(and there are clickable parts of the application behind that overlay).

**Question: How can the overlay be removed completely?**

Comment: Try changing `auto_dismiss` to `True`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson It does let you the option to just click outside one time and it will dismiss the overlay(and the popup overall). But still I was thinking about it as being a simple notification, maybe I use the wrong component for the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the wrong component for the job.

I simply changed Popup to BoxLayout, and added a method like so:

```
class AlertPopup(BoxLayout):
    def dismiss(self, *args):
        Window.remove_widget(self)
```

Instead of using .open() to show it, simply use `Window.add_widget(AlertPopup())`, and from there the dismiss method above will remove itself from its parent.